# Only enable SSL for specific websites (Aegir)

Tags: aegir, ssl

So Aegir has [a manual page on SSL](http://community.aegirproject.org/content/content/administrator/post-install-configuration/using-ssl).

I need to enable for one website. I enable SSL for the server and then require the certificate on that website.

But now, if I go to any other website on the same server and try the address with https://, it will present that incorrect certificate and a big error message comes up.

How can I enable SSL only for that one website I need and disable it completely for other sites?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a separate IP address for each site that uses SSL.  If you only have one IP address on the server and you assign it to SSL then the whole server is essentially using SSL.

So, solution is to assign a new IP address to the server and use that when you setup SSL for a site.

More info from this link: https://groups.drupal.org/node/74248

> all non-ssl sites will use the first ip address in the list.
>
> When a site has SSL enabled, it associates an IP address with the certificate it uses.
>   Both the SSL and non-SSL versions of all sites using the same SSL certificate will use the assigned IP.
>
> You can only host as many SSL certificate addresses as IP addresses you have on the server.
>
> The site node also now provides you with the list of IP addresses the site is running on.

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't work, the problem is still there. The server now has a pool of two IP addresses, and they both serve the same certificate for that one domain.